# OAUTH fail on authentication

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm a user getting an OAUTH fail when trying to login to FounderDating. I'm getting a confirmed email address issue when I've confirmed my email is valid with LinkedIn. This has happened on other sites as well. Any solutions from LinkedIn?

Comment: You need to follow up with FounderDating's support for a resolution to this one.  This really isn't the appropriate place to report an issue like this.

Comment: I was told by LinkedIn support that this is where to go for this answer.